# How can I find DNS config for multiple interfaces?

Tags: python, dns

Is there a way to find the configured DNS addresses for multiple interfaces in Python?

I'm running man-in-the-middle DNS proxy servers and HTTP servers to manipulate data for testing multiple set top boxes connected via multiple routers/interfaces/networks.

For names that are not redirected to my HTTP servers, I want to resolve using the DNS servers configured for the interfaces that requests came to. Some equipment is connected via a corporate intranet and needs to use the corporate nameservers. Equipment connected to the internet needs to use public nameservers.

Having identified the problem, I've replaced

```
socket.gethostbyname(name)
```

with dnspython to force the nameservers, but currently have a nasty bodge in place:

```
resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
if internet_connected:
    resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4']
else:
    # Intranet
    resolver.nameservers = ['x.x.x.25', 'x.x.x.26']
address = resolver.query(qname=name, rdtype=u"A")
```

I suppose I could add additional configuration to the tool, but I'd prefer to use whatever is already configured on the machine.

Comment: DNS configuration is not interface-specific, at least not on Unix/Linux.

Comment: Ah. It is (or at least appears to be) discrete on Windows. I need to it to be portable though. I'll  add the additional configuration to the tool.

Comment: I don't quite understand that aspect of Windows. How can you know which interface is going to be used until you get the address? And you have to use DNS to get the address.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I think that Windows' UI has (mis)led me to believe that the DNS config belongs to the interface, when it's probably really just a single fragmented resolv.conf.

Comment: I think it's because you may need different DNS config depending on whether you're connected to wireless or ethernet. If you have both, I assume it merges or prioritizes them somehow, but it's not dependent on the destination.